# Regex: Do not replace any char or digit from any language

Tags: javascript, regex

I used this regex to clear string from any non-alphanumeric characters

```
/[^0-9a-z]/gi
```

However, in my program there some strings with Arabic, Hebrew, Chinese and Dutch chars that are cleaned by this regex.
For future support I would like to use regex that will not clean any alphanumeric chars on any language.
Is it possible to create such one?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/qzLct95e/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
Thanks man. That what I was looking for!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is there is away to not replace spaces, I ve tried \s but it is not worked

Comment: `var rx = new XRegExp("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}\\s]+", "g");`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try it with a unicode escape.

[\u0041-\u005A] is the equivalent to [A-Z].

[\u0600—\u06FF] would be the arabic chars as an example.

The codes you can look up on:
https://unicode-table.com/en/

Also here they are grouped:
https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/control-character/